# Error when creating S3 bucket policy - Value of property PolicyDocument must be an object

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-serverless

I am trying to create cloudTrail through a serverless application.

```
CloudTrail:
  Type: AWS::CloudTrail::Trail
  Properties: 
    # CloudWatchLogsLogGroupArn: "String"
    # CloudWatchLogsRoleArn: "String"
    # EnableLogFileValidation: True
    # EventSelectors: 
    #   - EventSelector
    # IncludeGlobalServiceEvents: True
    IsLogging: True
    # IsMultiRegionTrail: True
    # KMSKeyId: String
    S3BucketName: {"Ref" : "CloudTrailBucket"}
    # S3KeyPrefix: String
    # SnsTopicName: String
    # Tags: 
    #   - Tag
    # TrailName: String
```

First I tried creating the cloudTrail alone and got the following error

```
CloudTrail - Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket: ....
```

Then I added this code to create a policy

```
CloudTrailBucketPolicy: 
  # Version : 2012-10-17,
  Type:  AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
  Properties:
    PolicyDocument:
      - Action:
          - "s3:GetBucketAcl"
        Effect:  Allow
        Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::CloudTrailBucket"] ] }
        Principal:  "*"
      - Action:
          - "s3:PutObject"
        Effect:  Allow
        Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::CloudTrailBucket", "/*" ] ] }
        Principal:
          Service:  cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
```

But getting this error.

```
An error occurred: CloudTrailBucketPolicy - Value of property PolicyDocument must be an object.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot `Statement`:

```
CloudTrailBucketPolicy: 
  # Version : 2012-10-17,
  Type:  AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref CloudTrailBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - "s3:GetBucketAcl"
            Effect:  Allow
            Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref CloudTrailBucket] ] }
            Principal:  "*"
          - Action:
              - "s3:PutObject"
            Effect:  Allow
            Resource: { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref CloudTrailBucket, "/*" ] ] }
            Principal:
              Service:  cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to accept your answer, just wondering first though have you any idea why this does not create the policy correctly, the only action i get in the policy on my s3 bucket is "Action": "s3:*", I was hoping for s3:GetBucketAcl and s3:PutObject

Comment: Did you change the bucket policy manually? Try delete CloudFormation stack and the bucket policy, after create stack again. Sometimes CloudFormation doesn't replace some manually changes I perform.

Comment: Yea I tried deleting the stack and even renaming it, any other ideas?

Comment: Did you create your bucket via CloudFormation too? When I created my BucketPolicy I also created the bucket via CloudFormation too

Comment: Yea I create the bucket in the script too, was your policy created correctly when you went in and checked in the console?

Comment: Yes, exactly equals. My last idea is about bucket name. You're using `{ "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::CloudTrailBucket", "/*" ] ] }`. What about try `{ "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", !Ref CloudTrailBucket, "/*" ] ] }`. Is the bucket name `CloudTrailBucket`? I've edited by answer.

Comment: Yea I have literally copied and pasted your new code and it creates the policy but the only action is s3:* . So annoying, i'll accept your answer, if you think of anything else let me know. your policy created with the 2 actions you mentioned yea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194249/discussion-between-pedro-arantes-and-mick-ogorman).